# Should I use XML for this situation?

Tags: xml

I am building a program that has different inputs and ouputs depending on the "vehicle" that is loaded.  I want people to be able to load different vehicles so I need some type of file that keeps track of all the information.

Is XML going to be the best way to do this?  Is there another option I should consider?

Thank you!

Comment: This question seems to be too generic. The answer, as it stands is: it depends. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is commonly used for the situation you described and there are plenty of tools out there to help with automatically creating and parsing XML so it's a solid choice.

Answer (score 0):

`XML` is used to fetch and get data.But if you have large type of data tracking in your program means,XML is bad option because the size of file get increased.
My opinion is use any one below

```
1.JSON
2.YAML
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is widely used for this kind of task and works well. It's especially suitable if you don't want the data to be tied to one particular program, for example you might want to do queries on the XML to select a subset of the data for processing: there are lots of tools for this kind of thing. On the other hand, depending on what language the program is written in, JSON may be simpler to read and write.